# Remove al text in a string from a certain character to a certain character

Tags: sed

I need remove all characters before a certain character until to the last occourence of the same character. In this case, from the first semicolon to the last semicolon, saving the last.

If I've:

> Word1;Word2;Word3

output desidered:

> Word1;Word3

Comment: See the sed man page or just google some examples - it doesn't get more basic than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple substitution:

```
sed 's/;.*;/;/'
```